# SelectBox replacement that allows html inside the options

Tags: jquery, css, select

I am looking for a select replacement that allows for good degree of customisation. In each option I want 2 fonts governed by CSS and structured by

```
<option><b>Option 1</b> options one</option>
```

Does anyone know a plugin that allows html styling like that.

Marvellous

Comment: Although it's still supported, `<strong>` is preferred over `<b>`. Not directly answering your question, but I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to plug that into the *amazing* jQuery "chosen" plugin:

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your budget is, but Telerik's RadComboBox is very customizable. You can even embed TreeViews and DataGrids in the select list.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx